# Removed View, but sound is still playing

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have a view that has some sounds playing. When I remove them using removeFromSuperview, the longer audio clips still play. Why does the sound continue even though the view is removed? Is it really gone; it seems like it's just hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it still play if you don't stop it. You need to stop it manually.
Before you remove you view write this :

```
[audioPlayer stop];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used AVAudioPlayer to play sounds, maybe you should call stop before you remove the views.